# Angular2 async issue with lodash library?

Tags: angular

I have a component that is subscribed to a behavior subject. My second component is subscribed to another behavior subject. It wants to receive data that we got back from our other component.

In my first subscription, once I have the data I use `lodash` to check if there an object in there with a specific `key/value`.

All I am expecting from that is a `true/false bool`. This is then what I send to my other subscription that my component #2 is listening for.

When trying to send the result from the `lodash` function to my other subscription, it never gets it. Is there some type of async issue here? Does `_find` have a callback I need to be using?

```
// Component 1 - Subscribed to a behavior subject. Upon receiving data, calls next on another behavior subject to send it some of the data we received

this._mapsService.uiMapVersionsData
    .subscribe(
        results => {
            if (results) {
                this.mapVersionsData = results;

                // Is there an async issue going on here with passing data to the lodash libary and getting its value back?
                this._mapsService.updateIsDraftData((_.find(results, { IsDraft: '1' }) ? true : false)); // Subscriber never gets anything

                // Other Tests
                this._mapsService.updateIsDraftData(false); // Subscriber receives false
                console.log((_.find(results, { IsDraft: '1' }) ? true : false)) // Prints false
            }
        }
    );


// Component 2 subscribed to another behavior subject trying to receive the data from component 1
this._mapsService.uiIsDraftData
    .subscribe(
        results => {
            if (results) {
                this.isDraft = results;
                console.log('I am a subscriber ' + this.isDraft)
            }
        }
    );


// Service
private uiIsDraftSub = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(null);
uiIsDraftData = this.uiIsDraftSub.asObservable();

....

updateIsDraftData(isDraft) {
    this.uiIsDraftSub.next(isDraft);
}
```

Comment: _.find is synchronous (btw, there's native `find`) and can't cause issues you're describing. It's impossible for the code above to ignore one `this._mapsService.updateIsDraftData(...)` and execute another, considering that they are called in sequence. How exactly do you test that *Subscriber never gets anything*? It's likely debugging issue rather than anything else. Consider providing http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve if the problem exists and can be replicated.

Comment: Thanks @estus - Figured out the problem. I am passing a `bool` to my behavior subject and its getting it just fine. However, my subscription is wrapping my `console.log` with `if(results)` resulting in it never firing for a false response. I updated my subscription to `<any>` and then passed `'True' : 'False'` instead so that it only executes if we have a result, and I get to see the result